# Divide Sequential Records

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table in MS Access like:

**table**

```
+-----+-----+-----+
| 1st | 2nd | 3rd |
+-----+-----+-----+
| A   |   1 | 100 |
| A   |   2 | 200 |
| A   |   3 | 300 |
| B   |   1 | 100 |
| B   |   2 | 200 |
| B   |   3 | 300 |
| C   |   1 | 100 |
| C   |   2 | 200 |
| C   |   3 | 300 |
+-----+-----+-----+
```

Now I want to read the values from the 3rd column, do some sort of manipulation to it and store them in to another table like:

**summary**

```
+-----+---------+---------+
| 1st |   2nd   |   3rd   |
+-----+---------+---------+
| A   | 100/200 | 200/300 |
| B   | 100/200 | 200/300 |
| C   | 100/200 | 200/300 |
+-----+---------+---------+
```

In another words, for `summary.2nd` this means:

```
select table.3rd FROM table where table.1st = A AND table.2nd = 1
```

divided by

```
select table.3rd FROM table where table.1st = A AND table.2nd = 3
```

Can someone give me a hint how this could be done?

Maybe VBA / ADO Recordset etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is conditional aggregation:

```
select [1st],
       max(iif([2nd] = 1, [3rd], null)) / max(iif([2nd] = 2, [3rd], null)) as [2nd],
       max(iif([2nd] = 2, [3rd], null)) / max(iif([2nd] = 3, [3rd], null)) as [3rd]
from t
group by [1st];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this SQL

```
INSERT INTO Summary 
SELECT DISTINCT a.[1st], 
                a.[3rd] / b.[3rd] AS [2nd], 
                a.[3rd] / c.[3rd] AS [3rd] 
FROM   ((tbl AS a 
         INNER JOIN tbl AS b 
                 ON a.[1st] = b.[1st]) 
        INNER JOIN tbl AS c 
                ON a.[1st] = c.[1st] ) 
WHERE  a.[2nd] = 1 
       AND b.[2nd] = 2 
       AND c.[2nd] = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another alternative, using calculated join criteria:

```
select 
    t1.[1st], 
    t1.[3rd]/t2.[3rd] as [2nd], 
    t2.[3rd]/t3.[3rd] as [3rd]
from 
    (
        [table] t1 inner join [table] t2 
        on t1.[1st] = t2.[1st] and t1.[2nd] = t2.[2nd]-1
    )
    inner join [table] t3 
    on t1.[1st] = t3.[1st] and t1.[2nd] = t3.[2nd]-2
```

Since the `2nd` column values 1, 2 & 3 are not hard-coded, this is applicable to any three integers in the `2nd` column whose values differ sequentially by one.

Change `[table]` to the name of your table.